# Express res.sendFile not doing anything

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I'm having some problems with express, I want to launch, by doing `localhost:3000/timer -> timetimer.html`, but it isn't working.

`server.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.status(404).send('Richiesta Sconosciuta');
    next();
});

app.listen(function () {
  console.log('Server in ascolto sulla porta 3000!');
});

module.exports = app;
```

`index.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/principale', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('/principale.html', {root: path.join(__dirname,'../public')});
});

router.get('/timer', function(req,res,next){
    //res.sendFile('public/timetimer.html', {root: path.join(__dirname,'../public')});
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/timetimer.html")
});


module.exports = router;
```

Structure of the folder:

[image]

The launch of the code works, i.e. it says that `server.js` is listening on 3000, but when I write `localhost:3000/timer` the browser is unable to reach the site

Comment: nvm i fixed it i'm dumb, i missed to write 3000 on app.listen(3000, function ()

Answer (score 1):

you didn't specify port in app.listen

try:

```
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Server in ascolto sulla porta 3000!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) is the directory name of the current module.

So it is the `routes` folder.

`timetimer.html` isn't in the `routes` folder, so you're passing it a non-existent path.